# Need help in accessing each row of an Int column using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to access each row of a specific Int column "numbers" to trace the previous row and next row in the numbers column. As a newbie, tried few samples as below, but I'm not able to solve it. I checked multiple sources online but couldn't rectify it. I do think list/collections might work, but I don't know how to implement it. Could someone help me in this.

I tried the below, but I'm getting error as "Int does not take parameters"

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

    val df = df_new.select($"tin", $"year",$"mnth",
   struct($"date_begin", $"date_end",$"start",$"end",$"usage",$"numbers")
    as "data").rdd.groupBy(x => (x.getString(0),x.getInt(1),x.getInt(2)))
    .map( x => {

        val tin = x(0).getString(0)
        val year = x(0).getInt(1)
        val month = x(0).getInt(2)
        val use = x(0).getStruct(3).getFloat(4)
        var sum:Float = 0.0F
        val nums = x(0).getStruct(3).getInt(5)


        for (i <- x.indices)
                 {
                      val v = x(i).getStruct(3)
                      val n = x(i).getStruct(3).getInt(5)
                      var next = n(i+1)
                      var prev = n(i-1)

                      if(nums == next || nums == prev)
                      {
                         sum  =  sum + v.getFloat(4)
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          sum 
                      }
                      }
                      (tin,year,nums)
                }
            )
```

I need to get data as below

```
 numbers            next             prev
   0                  1              null
   1                  0              0
   0                  1              1
   1                  1              0
   1                  0              1
   0                  1              1
   1                  1              0
   1                  1              1
   1                  1              1
   1                  0              1
   0                null             1
```

Comment: on which column?

Comment: @pme Hi, on the "numbers" column inside struct, specified the same in the description also

Comment: @pme Hi, could you please suggest any possible ways to achieve this, thank you in advance.

Comment: is this the line: `val nums = x(0).getStruct(3).getInt(5)` that gives the error (sorry I have no project with apache spark setup)

Comment: @pme I mainly need to know how to iterate through a specific column in scala, here the column is "numbers"
  like I need to compare the current value with previous value and current value with next value on a specific column, something like x(i+1) and x(i-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to compare two rows (as I have no Spark setup I use general Scala features).

If `l` is a `IterableLike`, e.g. a `Seq`or a `List` you have a function `sliding`.

So here is an example:

```
val l = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)

l.sliding(2) // gives you Seq(List(1,2),List(2,1)..)
 .map{case x::y::_ => //here you can compare these two values
```

In your case `x` and `y` is maybe a more complex type.

Comment: yeah, I tried this too, as you said its bit complex or I made it look complex , or this may not be possible in my scenario I'm not sure, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: try to simplify your question. introduce intermediate values and add types - so it is clearer